# jQuery toggle from different button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I want to do is to toggle an element when I click on a button. I have more buttons that trigger the toggle event. What is comes tricky a bit is if the div is already shown, is toggles to invisible than shown again. The point of this is that the element to be shown hold information generated by ajax.

I've made it to the point when this works, but the event chain is finished only if I click on the first button even clicked.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <button id="classOption1" class="btn btn-primary toggleOptions">firstButton</button>
    <button id="classOption2" class="btn btn-primary toggleOptions">secondBotton</button>
    <button id="classOption3" class="btn btn-primary toggleOptions">thirdButton</button>
    <button id="classOption4" class="btn btn-primary toggleOptions">yet another button</button>
</div>

<div class="classOptions">
    //some irrelevant HTML here
</div>
```

```js
$(".toggleOptions").click(function(){
    var trigger = $(".toggleOptions").attr('id');
    if (trigger != $(this).attr('id')) {
        $(".classOptions").toggle(1000).promise().done(function() {
            trigger = $(this).attr('id');
        });
        $(".classOptions").toggle(1000);
    } else {
        $(".classOptions").toggle(1000).promise().done(function() {
            trigger = $(this).attr('id');
        });
    }
});
```

If I click first on `firstButton`, then on `secondButton`, it works. But if I click again on `secondButton` to hide the element, is just hides and show again. However, if I click on `firstButton` again, it hides element as intended.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p3v6j7hp/) reproduction code.

I hope I made myself understand-able, not my first language.

Comment: Why are you repeating the toggle inside the if condition?: $(".classOptions").toggle(1000); if you remove it, I'm almost sure it works pretty well

Comment: Inside the if condition the element is shown, so I toggle it invisible then visible.

Comment: the like `var trigger = $(".toggleOptions").attr('id');` will always return `classOption1` since the selector will always catch all buttons.

Comment: Sorry if I did not understand well, but why don't you try to hide the element intentionally inside the if condition: [fiddle] http://jsfiddle.net/e8xaz89g/1/

Answer (score 0):

As I understood:

> ...what I want to do is to toggle an element when I click on a
>   button....
>
> ...is comes tricky a bit is if the div is already shown,
>   is toggles to invisible than shown again...

In this case you can change your selector to know if the element is visible or not like this:

```
var isVisible = $(".classOptions:visible").length > 0;
```

And if you want to make the div "blink" when already hidden just test it:

```
$(".toggleOptions").click(function(){
    var isVisible = $(".classOptions:visible").length > 0;

    $(".classOptions").toggle(1000);

    if(!isVisible){
        $(".classOptions").toggle(1000);
    }    
});
```

Sorry if I didn't understand you clearly.

[JSFiddle reproduction](http://jsfiddle.net/3qjeqqkk/1/)

Comment: The "blink" must happen when "//some irrelevant HTML here2" is visible and I click other button then previous one.

Comment: @LunguMihaiDan Let's clear things out: explain to me what need to happen in the first click, second click and third click. Because I believe is not this what you want too: http://jsfiddle.net/3qjeqqkk/9/

Comment: More like this, but without "blink" on first time. http://jsfiddle.net/3qjeqqkk/28/

Comment: @LunguMihaiDan In your example if I click a button after some interaction it blinks the first time and close the second time no matter which one had opened it. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this code `$(".classOptions").toggle(1000);` from your solution.

```
$(".toggleOptions").click(function(){
   var trigger = $(".toggleOptions").attr('id');
   if (trigger != $(this).attr('id')) {
       $(".classOptions").toggle(1000).promise().done(function() {
          trigger = $(this).attr('id');
       });
   } else {
       $(".classOptions").toggle(1000).promise().done(function() {
           trigger = $(this).attr('id');
       });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found the proper way, here's the code:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {

            var selector;
            var lastSelector = null;

            $(".toggleOptions").click(function(){

                selector = $(this).attr('id');

                if(lastSelector != selector && lastSelector != null){ //different button clicked or page just loaded
                    if($(".classOptions").is(":visible")){ // element is shown, so we hide and show again
                        $(".classOptions").toggle(1000); // toggle to invisible
                        $(".classOptions").toggle(1000).promise().done(function() {
                            lastSelector = selector;
                        });
                    } else { // element is hidden, just show it
                        $(".classOptions").toggle(1000).promise().done(function() {
                            lastSelector = selector;
                        });
                    }
                }

                if(lastSelector == selector || lastSelector == null){ // same button pressed twice, toggle as intended
                    $(".classOptions").toggle(1000).promise().done(function() {
                        lastSelector = selector;
                    });

                }


                $("#lastSelector").text("Last Selector: " + lastSelector);
                $("#thisSelector").text("Just Clicked: " + selector);

            });
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3qjeqqkk/32/
Thanks guys for help! Shame I can't vote up.